# How do i make double quit message confirmation when exit the program while timer is working?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code now:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to Exit. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    if (timer2.Enabled == true)
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show("Quit now will delete all the file of the current operation. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.Cancel = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

What i want to do is if timer2 is not enabled then quit ask the user to quit or not regular.

But if timer2 does enabled then first ask if to quit or not and then ask the second inner question "Quit now will delete all the file of the current operation" 
And if the user click yes on the second question do something(delete files) and quit.
But if the user click no on the second question do nothing keep the program running.

But now its not working good now if i click no on the first question then if the timer2 enabled is true it will ask for the secod question. If timer2 is true and i click yes on the first question it will quit the program without asking the second question.

A mess.

I want that i timer2 enabled is true ask the second question:
On second question user did YES delete file do anything need then close everything.
On second question user did NO return and keep the program working regular.

If timer2 enabled is false on first question if user did YES quit the program if the user did NO keep the program working regular.

Comment: your messages are quite difficult to understand could you please explain with example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified in two ways:

- Don't set `e.Cancel = false` - that's it's original value, there's no point in setting it.
- Invert your conditionals and `return` early - this reduces complicated nesting.

Also, I think you want to check your first MessageBox for `DialogResult.Yes`, not `No`.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.UserClosing)
        return;    // Not closing - we don't care.

    var res = (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to Exit? Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue",
        "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (res != DialogResult.Yes) {
        // User didn't say Yes - don't exit.
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;   
    }

    if (timer2.Enabled == true)
    {
        // Only ask this question if timer2 is running.
        res = MessageBox.Show("Quit now will delete all the file of the current operation. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue",
            "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (res != DialogResult.Yes) {
             e.Cancel = true;
             return;    // User didn't say Yes - don't exit.
        }
     }

     // Quit
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You only want to ask the user the second question if the timer is still enabled?
So do the following

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to Exit. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (timer2.Enabled == true)
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Quit now will delete all the file of the current operation. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        //do your work here like delete files etc
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Cancel = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
            }
        }
    }
```